# Is there a error in my scripts or is my editor just bugged

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, input

So I'm making my game engine's login and I'm running into a lot of errors with my MongoDB Scripts and my If Statement's seem to not work. Can someone help me with it?
This is the javascript that won't run for some reason and yet I dont see anything wrong with the code. Apparently my editor does and I'm wondering if it can be helped.

```js
var punct = "'"
var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
function adduser(){
  if(user.length > 5){
    if(pass.length > 5){
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://"+punct+document.getElementById("username").value+punct+":"+punct+document.getElementById("password").value+punct+"@cluster0.sc5bo.mongodb.net/AccountData?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
window.location.href = "https://rag3d-download.glitch.me/app-home"
    }
}
  
if(user.length < 5){
  if(pass.length < 5){
    alert("Username AND Password Needs To Be 5+ Characters")
  }
}
}
```

```css
center{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 90px;
}
html{
  color: white;
  background:black;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.global/63a42bac-4e7e-4d64-bb57-1057823f5775/download%20(9).png?v=1647105325819');
}
pre{
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  color: white;
}
b{
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;

}
button{
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 400px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  background:white;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
button:hover{
  background: grey;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#signup{
  top:25px;
  left:425px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
input{
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  border: 5px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Login To Rag3D</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <center>
  <div id="signup">
    <center>
    <pre>Email:</pre>
    <br /><input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"/><br /><br />
    <pre>Username:</pre>
    <br /><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/><br /><br />
    <pre>Password:</pre>
    <br /><input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br/><br/>
      <button >Create Account</button>
  </center>
  </div>
</center>
```

Can someone help me identify the errors in the code?
I really need it and will most likely give the helper credit. I just want my stuff to run smoothly because my IDE was already supposed to have been released, but I only got the scripting part done and nothing else since I am just only finding MongoDB. I used the connection code for the login scripts and I don't know what's happening. I feel like it might be my editor bugging out which is why I came here.

Comment: What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: @AHaworth it's just not working